# How to redirect to a new domain(url) using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am building a link shortener using spring boot. Everything is working except to redirect the user to the their url. I have checked other example on stackoverflow but nothing seems to be working for me.

**Please view my code below**

```java
public class DosuController {

    private final DosuService dosuService;

    public DosuController(DosuService dosuService) {
        this.dosuService = dosuService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{dosu}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> redirect(@PathVariable("dosu") String dosu) {
        return dosuService.redirect(dosu);
    }
}
```

```java
//SERVICE
public class DosuService {

    private final DosuRepo dosuRepo;

    public DosuService(DosuRepo dosuRepo) {
        this.dosuRepo = dosuRepo;
    }

    public ResponseEntity<Void> redirect(String dosu) {
        Dosu dosus = dosuRepo.findByDosu(dosu);
        if (dosus == null) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Dosu not found with name: +"dosu);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FOUND)
            .location(URI.create(dosus.getRedirectUrl())
            .build();
    }
}
```

**Output:  localhost:8080/www.google.com**

**Desire Output:  [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)**

Comment: try to return 30x http status code to let the browser redirect. @Maxwell D. Dorliea https://careydevelopment.us/blog/spring-boot-how-to-do-a-301-redirect

Comment: @Dolphin I am still get the same output

Comment: could you paste the http response about the request? @Maxwell D. Dorliea did you see the 30x redirect http status code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `URI` in the location headers as describe in the following code snippet. Make sure that you should add the proper `URI SCHEME` (like https mentioned in the uri). Ex:

```
  public ResponseEntity<Void> redirect() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setLocation(URI.create("https://www.google.com"));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
  }
```

Updated service class method

```
public ResponseEntity<Void> redirect(String dosu){
 Dosu dosus = dosuRepo.findByDosu(dosu);
 if(dosus == null){
  throw new ResponseStatusException (HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,"Dosu not found with name: +"dosu);
 }
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

 // Make sure uri should be valid uri with proper scheme name

 headers.setLocation(URI.create(dosus.getRedirectUrl()));
 return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check your `dosus.getRedirectUrl()` first. is this actual url what you expect?

Then, refactor your code, and try to return a `redirect:url` from your controller.

Controller:

```java
@GetMapping("/{dosu}")
public String redirect(@PathVariable("dosu") String dosu) {
    Dosu dosus = dosuService.findByDosu(dosu);
    if (dosus == null) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Dosu not found with name: " + dosu);
    }
    return "redirect:" + dosus.getRedirectUrl();
}
```

Service:

```java
public Dosu findByDosu(String dosu) {
    return dosuRepo.findByDosu(dosu);
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same output

Comment: What happen if you `return "redirect:https://www.google.com"`
 ? Does this bring you to google homepage correctly?

Comment: It redirect to localhost:8080/www.google.com